# Set Text of Textview async

Tags: c#, async-await, xamarin.android, android-asynctask, blocking

Language: C#, Xamarin.Android 
My Code:

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<string> Get()
{
    string url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall[..]"
    // The actual Get method
    using var result1 = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{url}");
    string content1 = await result1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content1
}
string content = await Get();
text.Text = content;
```

My Problem: 
Setting Text blocks the Main Thread 
Context: 
I tested it when my Syncfusion.Progressbar stops, by splitting the Code Up and use `Task.Delay(ms)`. I found out that it (Progressbar) shortly stops when setting the Text. So i assume that setting the Text blocks the MainThread. 
What is the proper way to asynchronously set the Text of the TextView? 
I tried Invoke, but there is no such function for me...

Please help me out

Comment: `asynchronously set the Text of the TextView` you can't.

Comment: @Codexer Is their any way to set the Text without blocking the Main Thread?

Comment: The UI/elements can only be updated from the UI thread, if you're not on it, then it doesn't work. How are you calling this code to set the `Text`, your code above wont compile as is. Can you try `RunOnUiThread(() => text.Text = content);` and see if that maybe helps?

Comment: It doesnt help. Here is the full code: https://gitea.kaaaxcreators.de/kaaax0815/AsyncWeather.Xamarin

Comment: @Codexer I found out, that TextView is bad showing much Text. WebView would be an alternative, but I dont want to generate HTML. Is there a good alternative to the TextView?

Comment: @kaaaxcreators What does the TextView is bad showing much Text mean? I tested the project you provided. The text shows when you start the app for a while.

Comment: If you see the Progressbar at the Top, it shortly stops when setting the content of the textview. It is bad performance wise to show large strings of text in a textview because it blocks the ui thread

Comment: @kaaaxcreators You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/BDRYOvr The Progressbar did not stop. Maybe i miss somthing.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT This is the old versions. I created a new version which shows the problem much better

Comment: I checked the sample code. When the text loading finished, the Progressbar stoped. I could not get the shortly stops. Do you make sure which step need more time? Could you try to load this part before your load the page?

Comment: for me, i start the app, then the bar shortly stops meanwhile the text updates and the bar disappers. everything fine but the bar shouldnt stutter.

Comment: Sorry for that. I could not reproduce.